# Why aren't these inner div's aligning?

Tags: html, css

Fiddle linked below

```
  #outer-container {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #outer-container .inner-container {
    width: 75vw;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  <div id="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div>a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div>b</div><div>bb</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-container">
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t4u1agwv/

I'm not sure why the inner div's aren't all aligning at the top of the outer div. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are `inline` elements, you can use the `vertical-align` property to fix this.

The default value for this property is `baseline`. That's why the first element is aligned at the base of the second element's text. Changing the property to values such as `top`/`middle`/`bottom` will change this.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/o5uav4xt/)

```
#outer-container .inner-container {
    width: 75vw;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```